# Can Swift structs self-delete?

Tags: swift, return, dependent-type

Consider the following:

```
struct MiniString {
    private(set) var value: String

    init(_ value: String) {
        if value.count < 17 {
            self.value = value
        } else {
            selfDeleteSomehow()
        }
    }
}
```

Elsewhere this could be instantiated thus:

```
var ms: MiniString? = MiniString("This string is too long to be accepted")
print(ms) // prints 'nil'
```

Context: my specific use-case is for a func declaration in a protocol that would return a `Double` between 0.0 and 1.0, but no higher or lower, something like:

```
protocol DoubleBetweenZeroAndOneProtocol {
    func getResult() -> DoubleBetweenZeroAndOne
}
```

Comment: What about a failable initializaer: `init?(_ seedValue: String) { guard seedValue.count < 17 else { return nil } value_ = seedValue }` Cf. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17

Comment: Little bit irrelevant, but why is there `var value`/`private let value_` separation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a failable initializer:

```
struct MiniString {

    var value: String { return value_ }

    private let value_: String

    init?(_ seedValue: String) {
        if seedValue.count < 17 {
            value_ = seedValue
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```